# [Cocos2d-x 3.8 win32]override draw method flickering texture

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I was trying to draw a blue rectangle at the lower half of screen by by creating a custom node and override it's draw method, at first it had no problem but after running about 10 seconds it appeared some weird verticle stripes flickering on the texture.

Here's my code:
**Water.cpp**

```
#define COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE Color4F(0.2 , 0.5, 1, 0.5)
#define COLOR_MIDNIGHT_BLUE Color4F(0, 0, 1, 1)

Water::Water(int w, int h, int segments){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    springsNum = segments + 1;

    springs = new Point[springsNum];
    vertices = new Point[springsNum * 2];
    colors = new Color4F[springsNum * 2];

    distanceBetweenSprings = (float)width / (float)segments;
    for (int i = 0; i < springsNum; i++){
        springs[i] = Point(i * distanceBetweenSprings, 0);
    }

}

void Water::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4& transform, uint32_t flags){
    setShaderProgram(ShaderCache::getInstance()->getProgram(GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_COLOR));
    CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
    GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION | GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_COLOR);

    auto customCommand = new CustomCommand();
    customCommand->init(getGlobalZOrder());
    customCommand->func = CC_CALLBACK_0(Water::onDraw, this);
    renderer->addCommand(customCommand);
}

void Water::onDraw(){
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < springsNum; i++){
        colors[j] = COLOR_MIDNIGHT_BLUE;
        vertices[j++] = springs[i];
        colors[j] = COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE;
        vertices[j++] = Point(springs[i].x, height);
    }

    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, springsNum * 2);
}
```

in main scene:

```
water = new Water(visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height / 2, visibleSize.width / 8);
this->addChild(water);
```

at first the game runs as expected, like this:
[image: normal]

but after about 10 secs the color messes up:
[image: stripped]

Can anyone show me what went wrong? thank you.

PS: i wanna keep the segments number high so that later i can create splash effect (http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-splash-with-dynamic-2d-water-effects--gamedev-236). If segments = 1, it runs fine. Also, when I set DebugDrawMask(DEBUGDRAW_ALL), the problem appears right from start.

SOLVED: Actually what did the trick was to move the 3 lines (setShaderProgram; CC_SETUP.. and enableVertexAttrib) into onDraw() which is called every frame.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question a week back, and since no one is answering I'll try and help you. I don't quite know what's causing your problem but I can give you a few pointers as to what can make your draw better, and might get rid of the problem.

1. Move your setShaderProgram out of your draw function, and do it only once
2. Move your set command out of the draw function to make sure your callback is only registered once and does not cause multiple callbacks (which can interfere with the draw order of certain things)

I have no idea if this will work, could you try those two things and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I solved this problem a while back but i forgot to update answer here on stack, but thank you for answering my question anyway. Actually what did the trick was to move the 3 lines (setShaderProgram; CC_SETUP.. and enableVertexAttrib) into onDraw() which is called every frame.